# Prove that the limit $\displaystyle\lim_{z\to 0} \frac{|z|^{2a}+i(\operatorname{Re}(z))^a}{z},\ 0<a<1$ does not exist.

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, complex-numbers

I am trying to prove that the limit
$$\lim_{z\to 0} \frac{|z|^{2a}+i(\operatorname{Re}(z))^a}{z},\ 0<a<1$$ does not exist.

My argument: Let $z=x>0$ (real number positive number), then the previous limit is equal to $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0} \ (x^{2a-1}+ix^{a-1})$ and consequently $\lim_{x\to 0} x^{a-1}$ is not a real number. So, the limit does not exist for all $a\in (0,1)$. Is it right?? Thanks.

Comment: Are you saying that $0+0i$ is not a real number?

Comment: Sorry is delete it I wrote it accidentally of cousre it is

Comment: What's the problem if that limit is not a real number?

Comment: I mean  that $\lim_{x\to 0} x^{a-1} $ is not a real number. Thus the general limit does not exist

Comment: I should rewrite better my solution previously

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a good approach. In order to eliminate that absolute value, it is better to restrict $x$ to the non-negative real numbers. There are two possibilites then:

- $0<a<\frac12$: then $ix^{a-1}$ takes purely imaginary values with arbitrarily large absolute value and $x^{2a-1}$ takes real values with arbitrarily large absolute value. So, the limit $\lim_{x\to0^+}x^{2a-1}+ix^{a-1}$ does not exist.
- $\frac12\leqslant a<1$: then $ix^{a-1}$ takes purely imaginary values with arbitrarily large absolute value and $\lim_{x\to0^+}x^{2a-1}\in\Bbb R$. So, again, the limit $\lim_{x\to0^+}x^{2a-1}+ix^{a-1}$ does not exist.

Comment: Thank you that is I mean!! Independently if $0<a<\frac12$ or $\frac12<a<1$ the problem is that for all $0<a<1$ the $ ix^{a-1}$ takes purely imaginary values with arbitrarily large absolute value (i.e the $ |ix^{a-1}|$ goes to $+ \infty $), and as a result the general limit not exist. Am I right?

Comment: No, you are not right. In principle, it could happen that the values taken by $x^{2a-1}$ could cancel those purely imaginary values with arbitrarily large absolute value. Of course, that actually cannot happen, but you have to say why. You can just say, for instance, that $x^{2a-1}\in\Bbb R$ if $x>0$.

Comment: If I get it right you mean that the convegent maybe it's happening due to cancelations, 
regardless who "big" is the real (or imaginary) part of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to approach the problem. With our loan of generality, assumption $r=|z|<1$. If one uses polar coordinates, the expression in your limit becomes

$$\frac{r^{2a} +ir^a|\cos\theta|^a}{re^{i\theta}}=r^{a-1}e^{-i\theta}\Big(r^a+i|\cos\theta|^a\Big)$$

There factor $r^{a-1}\xrightarrow{r\rightarrow0}\infty$, while the factor $(r^a+ I|\cos\theta|^a)$ is bounded away from $0$ for say $[0,\pi/2-\varepsilon]\cup[\pi/2+\varepsilon,3\pi/2-\varepsilon]\cup[3\pi/2+\varepsilon,2\pi]$ for any  fixed  small $\varepsilon>0$. If draw a picture, the region I'm describing is the interior of the circle where the inside of the circular sectors within an $\epsilon$ angle with respect to the $y$-axis.